# Problema Com Git

Tags: laravel, git

stou com um problema com o Github,

meu projeto é em laravel,

Crio o repositorio faço o envio comit->push
(consigo ver que o git pegou as modificações dentro dos arquivos)
mas quando faço o envio para o github os arquivos não são alterados
quando baixo os arquivos em outro pc atraves do git pull os arquivos
que são recebidos não são um espelho do que está no outro pc.

Isso seria por causa do laravel ?

Já usei o git pra php puro e isso está me chateando, com certeza sou eu que não estou sabendo usar mas alguma pessoa poderia me dar um help ou indicar uma forma de configurar o repositorio ou o proprio git pra que eu consiga subir os arquivos de forma a conseguir trabalhar numa boa, atualmente tenho que ficar transferindo o projeto por pendrive pra pegar atualizado.

Comment: poste o resultado do `git status` na pasta onde está seu repositório git e também do seu arquivo `.gitignore` (se houver um no projeto)

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser algum conflito entre as versões. Usa o `git status` para verificar se tem alguma informação, pois dependendo do caso ele não deixa você fazer alterações no repositório.

Em outro caso se necessário usa o `git clone` novamente em um novo diretório e testa para saber se o problema persiste.